# after 10 minutes of driving I decided to go back home

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

Could you please tell me if the tenses and the verbs in this sentence are correct? Some people told me that we can use 'go somewhere' only if we get there, but some teachers from UK told me that's not necessary since the time of the verb 'to go' refers to the start of the trip.

> Yesterday, I went to Moscow **at 8:20** and hoped to get there by 8:50, but at 8:30 after 10 minutes of driving I decided to go back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound odd to say that you 'went there' and immediately explain that you turned back. It would be better to say 'I set off for Moscow'.

Comment: Thank you! Does it only sound odd, or is it also incorrect?

Comment: You say you were told that 'going to' a place can refer to the start of the trip - but only if you actually did go there! Otherwise it's a bit nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, I got different opinions. But the idea of 'the time of the trip' and 'not necessarily getting there' I got from a great teacher who has written many grammar books and has created many Advanced English courses. So, I'm a little confused. What he says makes more sense to me, but other native speakers say the opposite.